# Retrieve elements within anonymous class using annotation processing

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I'm writing an annotation processor that needs to access elements that only exist within an anonymous class.  Specifically, accessing a method within an enum anonymous class.

```
enum Foo {
    BAR {
        @MyAnnotation
        void doSomething() { [...] }
    };

    @MyAnnotation
    void doSomethingElse() { [...] }
}
```

When calling `roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)` within the annotation process I do not get an element representing the `doSomething` method.  I do however, get an element representing the `doSomethingElse` method so it seems to be specific to anonymous classes.  I've observed the same for field annotations as well within an anonymous enum class.

What am I missing?  Is this sort of processing just not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't supported.

In Java, the *only* information the compiler has to tell it what methods are available on an object is the compile-time type of that object.  If a method isn't available on the known type of the object, it's not available as far as the compiler is concerned.